# How to findout the server controls in webmethod using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I have written my webmethod in aspx.cs file , but when i call n.Nautilus() method in same page , **i am unable to get the server side controls in Nautilus(), in this method controls becoming NULL** , please find the reasons and solution to this problem as soon as possible.

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string Execute4()
        {
            NewQuote2 n = new NewQuote2();

            JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string r = string.Empty;
            var o = Observable.Start(() =>
            {
                // Thread.Sleep(7000);
                PennStar pn = new PennStar();
                r = j.Serialize(new { res = n.Nautilus() });
            }, Scheduler.NewThread);
            o.First();
           // r = n.Nautilus();
            return r;
        }

    public string Nautilus()
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ddlLineCode.SelectedItem.Value == "GL")
            {
                deductible = Convert.ToInt32(ddlGLdeductible.SelectedItem.Text);
                //ClassCode = Convert.ToInt32(ddlClassCode1.SelectedValues.ToString());
                ClassCode = Convert.ToInt32(ddlClasscode.SelectedValue);
            }
            else if (ddlLineCode.SelectedItem.Value == "PP" || ddlLineCode.SelectedItem.Value == "PR")
            {
                deductible = Convert.ToInt32(ddlPropdeductible.SelectedValue);
            }
            string T = ddlTerritory.SelectedItem.Text;

            QMSRatingEngine.Nautilus QR = new QMSRatingEngine.Nautilus();
            ArrayList Result = new ArrayList();

            if (LC == "GL")
            {
                QMSRatingEngine.NautilusAgents.ReturnGLRate gl = QR.GLRateObject(state, ED, deductible, ClassCode, ddlLimit.SelectedItem.Text, T);
                Result.Add(gl);
                getNautilusRatedata(gl);//this method code i can write the bellow
            }
            if (LC == "PP" || LC == "PR")
            {
                QMSRatingEngine.NautilusAgents.ReturnPropRate PRop = QR.PropertyRateObject(state, ED, ddlPropFormtype.SelectedItem.Text, ddlPropconstructiontype.SelectedItem.Text, ddlPropcovergetype.SelectedItem.Text, deductible, ddlPropuwscale.SelectedItem.Text, ddlPropprotectionclass.SelectedItem.Text, T);
                Result.Add(PRop);
            }
    }
return lbltext.Text;
    }

 private void getNautilusRatedata(QMSRatingEngine.NautilusAgents.ReturnGLRate gl)
        {
            lblNautilusPremiumbasis.Text = GetPremiumBasisFormat(txtExposure.Text);
            lblNautilusDeductible.Text = getCurrencyFormat(ddlGLdeductible.SelectedItem.Text);
            string Type = ddlPremiumBasis.SelectedItem.Text;
            decimal Premium = Convert.ToDecimal(gl.BaseRate_Prem.ToString());
            decimal nautilusPremiumBasis = Convert.ToDecimal(txtExposure.Text);
            decimal Prod = Convert.ToDecimal(gl.BaseRate_Prod.ToString());
            decimal CalcPremium = 0, CalcProd = 0;
            if (Type == "A - AREA" || Type == "M - ADMISSION" || Type == "U - UNITS" || Type == "O - OTHER")
            {
                CalcPremium = (Premium * nautilusPremiumBasis);
                lblNautilusPremisesOp.Text = getCurrencyFormat(Math.Round(CalcPremium).ToString());
                CalcProd = (Prod * nautilusPremiumBasis);
                lblNautilusProductsCoop.Text = getCurrencyFormat(Math.Round(CalcProd).ToString());
            }
            if (Type == "C - TOTAL COST" || Type == "P - PAYROLL" || Type == "S - GROSS SALES")
            {
                CalcPremium = (Premium * nautilusPremiumBasis) / 1000;
                lblNautilusPremisesOp.Text = getCurrencyFormat(Math.Round(CalcPremium).ToString());
                CalcProd = (Prod * nautilusPremiumBasis) / 1000;
                lblNautilusProductsCoop.Text =getCurrencyFormat(Math.Round(CalcProd).ToString());
            }
            lblNautilusGLPremium.Text = getCurrencyFormat(Math.Round((Math.Round(CalcProd) + Math.Round(CalcPremium))).ToString());
            lblNautilusSubTotal.Text = getCurrencyFormat(Math.Round((Math.Round(CalcProd) + Math.Round(CalcPremium))).ToString());
            lblNautilusGrandTotal.Text = getCurrencyFormat(Math.Round((Math.Round(CalcProd) + Math.Round(CalcPremium))).ToString());

            //string jstablelattest = "moneyCoverage";
            //ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource(this.GetType(), jstablelattest);
        }
```

Comment: found them! really - "as soon as possible"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are calling `Nautilus()` function from `public static string Execute4()` and because `Execute4()` is a `webmethod` and thus `static` you are not able to find any controls as they are not static.

You should try to return the results and values from your `webmethod` and do the operations like show/hide divs and other stuff with those results on the client side.

Comment: But I have write the more code in Nautilus() method , that code doesnot write the client side ,(i can change the code check it) and give me example